# RDD String to Spark csv Reader

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read the `RDD[String]` using the spark CSV reader. The reason I am doing this is, I need to filter some records before using the CSV reader.

```
val fileRDD: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file")
```

I need to read the fileRDD using the spark CSV reader. I wish not to commit the file as it increases the IO of the HDFS. I have looked into the options we have in the spark CSV, but didn't found any.

```
spark.read.csv(file)
```

Sample Data

```
PHM|MERC|PHARMA|BLUEDRUG|50
CLM|BSH|CLAIM|VISIT|HSA|EMPLOYER|PAID|250
PHM|GSK|PHARMA|PARAC|70
CLM|UHC|CLAIM|VISIT|HSA|PERSONAL|PAID|72
```

As you can see all the records starts with PHM has different number of columns and clm has different number of columns. That is the reason i am filtering and then applying schema. PHM and CLM records has different schema.

```
val fileRDD: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file").filter(_.startWith("PHM"))


 spark.read.option(schema,"phcschema").csv(fileRDD.toDS())
```

Comment: I dont see real reason for reading text file and populating again in to CSV reader and making a dataframe. with dataframe it self you can do these checks and filter. what you are doing is a round trip. AFAIK I feel its unnecessary

Comment: moreover RDD uses java serialization where as dataframe uses tungstun binary format which is more efficient than RDD

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram The file has different schemas, I have to filter it out before applying schema. That the reason in order to do this. I am actually looking for filter with in csv reader,its not present

Comment: yeah in that case you can mention the file with sample records with different schemas. you may get elegant solution by the answerers.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Can you elaborate, i didnt understood.

Comment: put your sample data which is in file in the question is what i mean

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Provided the Sample Data

Comment: The title is odd

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 2.2, method ".csv" can read dataset of strings. Can be implemented in this way:

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile("csv.txt")
// ... do filtering
spark.read.csv(rdd.toDS())
```